# Better way to use re.sub

Tags: python, html, regex, html-parsing

I'm cleaning a series of sources from a twitter stream. 
Here is an example of the data:

```
source = ['<a href="https://twitter.com/download/android" rel="nofollow">Twitter for Android Tablets</a>', 
          '<a href="https://twitter.com/download/android" rel="nofollow">Twitter for  Android</a>',
          '<a href="http://foursquare.com" rel="nofollow">foursquare</a>', 'web',
          '<a href="http://twitter.com/download/iphone" rel="nofollow">Twitter for iPhone</a>',
          '<a href="http://blackberry.com/twitter" rel="nofollow">Twitter for BlackBerry</a>']


import re
for i in source:
    re.sub('<.*?>', '', re.sub(r'(<.*?>)(Twitter for)(\s+)', r'', i))

### This would be the expected output ###
'Android Tablets'
'Android'
'foursquare'
'web'
'iPhone'
'BlackBerry'
```

The later is the code i have that does the job but looks awful. I was hoping there is a better way of doing this including `re.sub()` or other function that could be more approapiate.

Comment: `s[s.index('>')+1:s.rindex('<')]`. By the way: instead of `.*?` I'd use `[^>]*`.

Comment: @Bakuriu thx for the comment. What would be the explanation of `[^>]*` ?

Comment: see my answer, it's matching any character that is not a `>`, which means everything that is within a tag in your context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here are advices to improve upon your code:

- Use regex compilation so you don't process the regex each time you apply the regex,
- use raw strings to avoid any interpretation of the regex string by python,
- use a regex that takes anything but the closing tag character for matching within the tag
- you don't need to repeat the substitution as it's matching every occurance on the line per default

here's a simpler and better result:

```
>>> import re
>>> r = re.compile(r'<[^>]+>')
>>> for it in source:
...     r.sub('', it)
... 
'Twitter for Android Tablets'
'Twitter for  Android'
'foursquare'
'web'
'Twitter for iPhone'
'Twitter for BlackBerry'
```

N.B.: the best solution for your use case would be @bakuriu's suggestion:

```
 >>> for it in source:
 ...     it[it.index('>')+1:it.rindex('<')]
'Twitter for Android Tablets'
'Twitter for  Android'
'foursquare'
'Twitter for iPhone'
'Twitter for BlackBerry'
```

which adds no important overhead and uses basic, fast string operations. But that solution takes *only* what is *between* tags, instead of removing it, which may have side effects if there are tags within the `<a>` and `</a>` or no tags at all, i.e. it won't work for the `web` string. A solution against no tags at all:

```
 >>> for it in source:
 ...     if '>' in it and '<' in it:
 ...         it[it.index('>')+1:it.rindex('<')]
 ...     else:
 ...         it
 'Twitter for Android Tablets'
 'Twitter for  Android'
 'foursquare'
 'web'
 'Twitter for iPhone'
 'Twitter for BlackBerry'
```

Comment: +1 for the regex solution. The bakuriu's one doesn't work because of the 'web' case. It has no '<' or '>'. However it's interesting to hear about it as i'm extremely new in python.

Comment: I'll use the following: `r = re.compile(r'(<[^>]+>)|(Twitter for\s+)')` in order to get rid of the Twitter for part.

Answer (score 4):

Just another alternative, using [`BeautifulSoup`](http://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) html parser:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> for link in source:
...     print BeautifulSoup(link, 'html.parser').text.replace('Twitter for', '').strip()
... 
Android Tablets
Android
foursquare
web
iPhone
BlackBerry
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're doing a lot of these, use a library designed to handle (X)HTML. `lxml` works well but I'm more familiar with the BeautifulSoup wrapper.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

source = ['<a href="https://twitter.com/download/android" rel="nofollow">Twitter for Android Tablets</a>', 
      '<a href="https://twitter.com/download/android" rel="nofollow">Twitter for  Android</a>',
      '<a href="http://foursquare.com" rel="nofollow">foursquare</a>', 'web',
      '<a href="http://twitter.com/download/iphone" rel="nofollow">Twitter for iPhone</a>',
      '<a href="http://blackberry.com/twitter" rel="nofollow">Twitter for BlackBerry</a>']

soup = BeautifulSoup('\n'.join(source))
for tag in soup.findAll('a'):
    print(tag.text)
```

This might be a little overkill for your use case, though.

Answer (score 1):

One option, if the text really is in this consistent of a format, is to just use string operations instead of regex:

```
source = ['<a href="https://twitter.com/download/android" rel="nofollow">Twitter for Android Tablets</a>', 
          '<a href="https://twitter.com/download/android" rel="nofollow">Twitter for  Android</a>',
          '<a href="http://foursquare.com" rel="nofollow">foursquare</a>', 'web',
          '<a href="http://twitter.com/download/iphone" rel="nofollow">Twitter for iPhone</a>',
          '<a href="http://blackberry.com/twitter" rel="nofollow">Twitter for BlackBerry</a>']

for i in source:
    print i.partition('>')[-1].rpartition('<')[0]
```

This code finds the first '>' in the string, takes everything after it, finds the first '<' in what remains, and returns everything before that; e.g., giving you any text between the first '>' and the last '<'.

There's also the far more minimal version @Bakuriu put in a comment, which is probably better than mine!

Answer (score 1):

This looks less ugly to me and should work equally well:

```
import re
for i in source:
    print re.sub('(<.*?>)|(Twitter for\s+)', '', i);
```